Unable to bind `C-k` in comint / inferior-python mode
I want to use C-k to go to previous input when using the Python REPL.
I'm using doom emacs.
I have this in bindings/+python.el:
(map!
 :after python
 :map inferior-python-mode-map
 "C-j" :i #'comint-next-input
 "C-k" :i #'comint-previous-input)

But it does not work, the key combination points to another function.


Wrong placement of :i.
Changed to
(map!
 :after python
 :map inferior-python-mode-map
 :i "C-j" #'comint-next-input
 :i "C-k" #'comint-previous-input)

and it works.
